# Downloading file from ubuntu server through html

Tags: html, ubuntu

I have my domain pointing at a ubuntu server hosted by amazon ws, and I have my index.html file that gets loaded when someone makes a request to my domain, in the same folder of that index.html file I have another file, and I would like to make it possible to download it from my website. How can I achieve that? I tried with an iframe tag, and giving it src="./myfile.jpg" but the server tries to look for it at www.mydomain.com/myfile.jpg   and it can't find it there. Can anyone give me any suggestions?
Btw my files are inside /var/www/html folder, which from what I understood is the default folder for public files on ubuntu.

Comment: Have you got any .htaccess file in that folder? is the index.html file accessible via a browser (i.e. when you do http://www.YOURDOMAIN.COM/index.html

Comment: I just realized that my domain is actually pointing at some aws "buckets", and there I can upload html pages and other files to share, all through the aws console. But now my question is, how can I instead redirect my domain to a specific html page inside my ubuntu server?